# Excel cell to image convert

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have one excel file which have 10 cells convert these cells text to images. there are total 10 images generated.

one to one, excel cell to image convert I need.

Answer (score 0):

Click in A1, hold down Shift, select Edit > Copy Picture, click in B2, Edit > Paste.

Comment: no,I need all cells to images at once respectively.